# Fill ListView from SparseArray

Tags: java, android, listview

I am new to the concept of listviews and arrays. I basically have a SparseArray named shop.Clothes.
I basically want to fill my listView with the elements of shop.Clothes. In order to do that i understood that i have to create an ArrayAdapter and pass the parameters of the adapter to the listview. After that i must check if shop.clothes contains a value and if it does it must add it to the listView.

Java:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.redeem_shop_list , shop.Clothes);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    int key = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shop.Clothes.size(); i++) {
        key = shop.Clothes.keyAt(i);
        Object value = shop.Clothes.valueAt(i);
        value.toString();

        if(i==0){
            listView.add((String) value);
        }
    }
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It seems i am doing something wrong, i get these errors :

```
Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(SearchableShopList, int, android.util.SparseArray<java.lang.string>)

Cannot resolve method 'add(java.lang.String)'
```

Can somebody help me on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a very simple manner. Instead of making a custom adapter for the SparseArray, i just passed the value of the SparseArray to another array and that did the trick !

```
ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

    int key = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shop.Clothes.size(); i++) {
        key = shop.Clothes.keyAt(i);
        Object value = shop.Clothes.valueAt(i);
        value.toString();
        mylist.add((String) value);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist );
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```